# Django, DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) not working

Tags: django

I am a newbie of Django. This is the problem I have encountered.

models.py:

`created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time', auto_now_add=True)`

When I migrations:
[image: migrations error]

Then, I add the default to it:

`created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time', auto_now_add=True, default=timezone.now)`

I migrations it again:
[image: migrations error2]

So, can somebody tell me how to use DateTimeField with auto_now_add=True?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says, you can't set `auto_now_add=True` and specify a default at the same time.

The problem is that Django needs to know what value to use for your existing entries in the database.

You can either set `null=True`, then the value will be left as `None`.

```
created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time', auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Or, simply remove the default, and run makemigrations again.

```
created_time = models.DateTimeField('Created Time', auto_now_add=True)
```

When Django prompts you, select Option 1), and specify a default (e.g. `timezone.now`).